# How can I remove user Stories from web Facebook (top-right)?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way I can remove a specific user from the Stories box at the top-right or remove the Stories box altogether?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a browser extension called **FB Purity**, it has an option to hide the Stories box.

To hide it using **FB Purity**, install the FB Purity extension
then open the **FBP** options screen by clicking the **FBP** link in the top navigation bar of the facebook page, then click the "**Hide Right Column Links**" heading, then tick the Hide "**Stories**" option, then click the "**Save and Close**" button.

You can get FB Purity here: http://fbpurity.com